# How to fit image in PictureBox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was set in PictureBox is:

`pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;`

But the result I receive is pictureBox1.Image very large.

How to fit the image in PictureBox?

I created gif animation to describe my problem.

Note:
In this gif image, pictureBox is custom control I added. And the parent of `pictureBox1` is a `pictureBoxParent`. I create program to insert text(label) or logo(pictureBox) in main background image.

Update:
I add more code to show in gif I did.
This button creates a new PictureBox name `ctrl`.

```
public PictureBox ctrl = new PictureBox();

public void btnAddLogo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randNumber = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
    String picName = "Pic_" + randNumber;
    //ctrl = new PictureBox();
    ctrl.Location = new Point(200, 170);
    ctrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 60);
    ctrl.Name = picName;
    ctrl.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    ctrl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("NativePrinterFontA", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Chocolate;
    ctrl.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(control_MouseEnter);
    ctrl.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(control_MouseLeave);
    ctrl.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
    ctrl.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
    ctrl.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);
    picPreview.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    btnBackgroundImage.Enabled = true;
}
```

I've added ImageBackGround to `ctrl` PictureBox.

```
private void btnBackgroundImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
    choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
    if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string sFileName = choofdlog.FileName;
        ctrl.Image = Image.FromFile(sFileName);
        ctrl.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

In button save the image, I call again ctrl.SizeMode but not happen.

```
ctrl.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
g.DrawImage(ctrl.Image, Point.Round(StretchImageSize(postPoint, picPreview)));
```

[Describe my problem when using SizeMode in PictureBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK8rI.jpg)

Comment: your gif animation is too fast to make any sense out of it, please make a demo and post the link, or post your relevant piece of code.

Comment: I was edit link to image full and slow.

Comment: I was edit full question with more code. Thanks @Phani

Comment: on an unrelated matter, `int randNumber = rnd.Next(1, 1000);` does not guarantee distinct names. There is an increasing 0.1% probability to have a control with the same name per image added. You may try `Guid`.